# Check more than one directories for files with certain extension?

Tags: python

I have this code that finds files with that extension and removes them.

How can i search in two directories? `out` and `out2`

```
import os

out = path
out2 = path2

test = os.listdir(out)
for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".cpg"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(out, item))
```

Without typing it again with the second directory?

Note: All of this is part of a `for` loop.

Comment: So... "how do I iterate over multiple values?"? Use a list and a for loop.

Comment: write a function

Comment: Turn it into a function and call it for ``out`` and ``out2``. Or add your pathes to a list and iterate over them in a loop that wraps your current loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it a function for it:

```
import os

out = path
out2 = path2

directory_search(out)
directory_search(out2)

def directory_search(out):
    test = os.listdir(out)
    for item in test:
        if item.endswith(".cpg"):
            os.remove(os.path.join(out, item))
```

Or you coulld make a list and iterate through:

```
import os

list_of_out = [path, path2]
for out in list_of_out:
    test = os.listdir(out)
    for item in test:
        if item.endswith(".cpg"):
            os.remove(os.path.join(out, item))
```

Or I guess if you really wanted to, make a function that takes a list:

```
import os

out = [path, path2]
directory_search(out)

def directory_search(list_of_out):
    for out in list_of_out:
            test = os.listdir(out)
            for item in test:
                if item.endswith(".cpg"):
                    os.remove(os.path.join(out, item))
```

Comment: is the function using the out2?

Comment: Yes. Since you are calling it twice with different `out`

Comment: See `directory_search(out2)`\

Comment: Can you add a function that would take a list of any amount of paths like the example you made as well?Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Goto directory level like C:/,d:/ : in directory level for loop go through all files and folders then in each folders go through each files and folders. You can use LinkedList/Array for folders to be scanned and one by one scan them

Comment: This is awkward idea. Imagine huge file system (10 TB FS are nothing exceptional) with thousands of directories. It would be sooooooooooo sluggish.

Comment: @Alex Baranowski Hmm ! It will be sluggish. But he has only two directories to work with but,There always a better way

Comment: My understanding for your answer is like "Start with C:/" then recursive through whole partition. BTW Minus is not mine :).